# Can thread trying to std::lock[_unique] an std::shared_mutex be starved by threads calling std::lock_shared?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, c++14

A question regarding `std::shared_mutex` and the acquiring of `unique_lock`.

Assume there are 3 threads:

- 2 readers (trying to `lock_shared()` the `std::shared_mutex`), and
- 1 writer (trying to `lock[_unique]()` the `std::shared_mutex`)

Is it possible that the writer trying to `lock[_unique]()` would be starved? E.g.: at all times at least one reader owns a `std::shared_lock`, and `lock[_unique]()` can never succeed.

More or less: would `lock[_unique]()` on a `std::shared_mutex` block any attempts to further `lock_shared()` it?

---

(pretty sure `boost::upgrade_lock` could work here, but I'd like to know if there's any guarantee for bare `std::unique_lock` on a `std::shared_mutex`)

Comment: What do you mean by `lock[_unique]()` the `std::lock` function or a `std::unique_lock`?

Comment: just the std::shared_mutex.lock() function

Comment: Then I guess it would be best to remove the unique part?

Comment: @inf: I disagree - it's standard notation for edits/explanations; the parentheses suggest it's a function, all in all it nicely contrasts with the lock_shared()

Comment: I don't see an advantage of using a function name that doesn't exist. `lock_shared` and `lock` are distinctive enough.

Comment: I can't find any reference that would suggest starvation freedom is guaranteed , so I guess it is possible  (depending on the implementation).

Comment: And BTW `std::shared` mutex doesn't exist in c++11 or 14 but will (most likely) br intrisuced with c++17.

Comment: @MikeMB: thank you for the information. I'd argue it limits the functionality of the shared_mutex but that's a different story.

Comment: [N2406 - shared_mutex Reference Implementation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html) : _"A secondary motivation is to explain the lack of reader-writer priority policies in shared_mutex. This is due to an algorithm credited to Alexander Terekhov which lets the OS decide which thread is the next to get the lock without caring whether a unique lock or shared lock is being sought. This results in a complete lack of reader or writer starvation. It is simply fair."_ But this only describes the reference implementation and not necessarily the one used in the std libs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> More or less: would `lock[_unique]()` on a `std::shared_mutex` block any attempts to further `lock_shared()` it?

The standard doesn't specify whether that should happen or not, it only says:

> *Effects:* Blocks the calling thread until shared ownership of the mutex can be obtained for the calling thread.

So it's left up to the implementation whether it makes later readers wait behind pending writers or not.

If the implementation wants to prevent writer starvation then it might need to have a "writer waiting" flag that is set when a thread tries to obtain a unique lock, so that later attempts to get a shared lock will block, waiting behind the unique locker. In the N2406 reference implementation this is the `write_entered_` bit in the `state` member.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tested the implementation I use for this behaviour (avoiding writer starvation, when it waits for unique_lock) sometime ago and it indeed was it. Unfortunately it's not guaranteed on other platforms.

Comment: Just tested (in 2023, on Linux): gcc+libstdc++ allows starvation, while clang+libc++ does not. Online: https://godbolt.org/z/3675cj55b